# Running multiple Angular Apps on common node server

Tags: node.js, angular, express, mean-stack

I am new to the mean stack. I want to build application having admin and client. So I built two angular 2 apps in my node. But I am not able to render admin app and client app based on router. For example when router is / my client app should render and on /admin my admin app should render.

Please help me to structure my directory an solution to my problem .I am using express for Routing.

Comment: if you are building two separate applications just give a link(**localhost:3005**) to the Admin from Client having **Admin deployed at the 3005** port

Comment: not able to get ur point

Comment: reach me out in fb  @aravind2109

Comment: When you are doing two different apps, then you mean different Angular2-Projects for this? Well, Angular2 with Webpack is producing a dist folder, so you can configure two different routes for two different dist folders just referencing the index.html file in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign different port to your both apps.

```
ng serve --port 4210 --live-reload-port 4950
```

Open your second project and fire above command.

See : [Click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141131/angular2-running-two-projects-with-cli)