# Create multiple application from one Angular 9 project

Tags: angular, angular-cli, angular9, angular-json

My goal is to have one Angular project with shared parts: functionality, classes, look, services and page components (header, footer, some directives). Then inside it has 2 (or more applications) that will use the shared parts and add on the top of it own components (pages) and routes.

Then these 2 application should build to different dist folders, so the can be deployed to different places (URLs). And I want to be able to run (serve) them at the same time (maybe on different ports).

I guess I should start with creating new applications inside project:

```
ng generate application app1 --routing
ng generate application app1 --routing
```

and library? (for shared components). Is that right?

How should I configure angular.json file for serve and build?
And how should I configure app.module.ts files?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Direct from the Angular Guide [Workspace and project file structure - Multiple projects](https://angular.io/guide/file-structure#multiple-projects)

> ### Multiple projects
>
> A multi-project workspace is suitable for an enterprise that uses a single repository and global configuration for all Angular projects (the "monorepo" model). A multi-project workspace also supports library development.
>
> #### Setting up for a multi-project workspace
>
> If you intend to have multiple projects in a workspace, you can skip the initial application generation when you create the workspace, and give the workspace a unique name. The following command creates a workspace with all of the workspace-wide configuration files, but no root-level application.
>
> ```
> ng new my-workspace --createApplication="false"
> ```
>
> You can then generate apps and libraries with names that are unique within the workspace.
>
> ```
> cd my-workspace
> ng generate application my-first-app
> ```
>
> #### Multiple project file structure
>
> The first explicitly generated application goes into the `projects/` folder along with all other projects in the workspace. Newly generated libraries are also added under `projects/`. When you create projects this way, the file structure of the workspace is entirely consistent with the structure of the [workspace configuration file](https://angular.io/guide/workspace-config), `angular.json`.
>
> ```
> my-workspace/
>   ...             (workspace-wide config files)
>   projects/       (generated applications and libraries)
>     my-first-app/ --(an explicitly generated application)
>       ...         --(application-specific config)
>       e2e/        ----(corresponding e2e tests)
>          src/     ----(e2e tests source)
>          ...      ----(e2e-specific config)
>       src/        --(source and support files for application)
>     my-lib/       --(a generated library)
>       ...         --(library-specific config)
>       src/        --source and support files for library)
> ```
>
> ### Library project files
>
> When you generate a library using the CLI (with a command such as `ng generate library my-lib`), the generated files go into the projects/ folder of the workspace. For more information about creating your own libraries, see [Creating Libraries](https://angular.io/guide/creating-libraries).
>
> Libraries (unlike applications and their associated e2e projects) have their own `package.json` configuration files.
>
> Under the `projects/` folder, the `my-lib` folder contains your library code.

It continues on in a table to describe library project files and their purpose. I'd suggest reading up further on the documentation above and associated links as it is well documented and might get you up and running quickly.

To run multiple Angular apps on different ports just open another terminal and run `ng serve --port 1234` for each app. See [Angular(2) - Running two projects with CLI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141131/angular2-running-two-projects-with-cli)

Comment: Thanks. I asked a follow up question. https://stackoverflow.com/q/61343113/1351452

Comment: Does this have a special treatment on deploy or angular should know alone to handle the deploy of an angular workspace with multiple apps?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you want to use a monorepo approach. I'd recommend using https://nx.dev/angular.

Comment: Thanks. I will try the above solution (without using the additional libraries) first.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend different projects for different apps and either do one of the following

1. Have the reusable code into packages you can publish and install for each of your projects
2. Make use of git submodules to hold the reusable code and install the git submodule for each of your projects

I'd prefer option 2 to 1